# link list printing issue?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I try to print a linked list but it didn't print all of the member in the list.can you explain what is the issue in my code? is code line (newhead=newhead->next) moves even the rest of the list is on the another function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test_struct{
  int data;
  struct test_struct *next;
};

struct test_struct* create();
void add_node();
int main()
{
  add_node();

  return 0;
}

void add_node()
{
  struct test_struct* head = create();
  struct test_struct* newhead;
  newhead = malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
  newhead->data=2;
  newhead->next=head;
  head=newhead;
  while(newhead->next != NULL)
  {
    printf("%d\n",newhead->data);
    newhead=newhead->next;
  }



}


struct test_struct* create()
{

  struct test_struct* head=NULL;
  struct test_struct* temp = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
  if(NULL==temp)
  {
    printf("error in memory");
    return 0;
  }
  temp->data=5;
  temp->next=head;
  head=temp;

  return head;
}
```

Comment: What output did you expect? What output did you get?

Comment: I want out put as 2   5.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop stops when it is on a node with no `next` node; it doesn't print the data on that node.

Instead, you want to stop when it is pointing to no node; that is, just after it's "fallen off the end" of your list:

```
while(newhead != NULL)
{
    printf("%d\n",newhead->data);
    newhead=newhead->next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 26 should be `while (newhead != NULL)`.

If you want to keep growing this, you could also review the purpose of each function, since `add_node()` and `create()` are doing almost the same thing, plus `add_node()` also prints the list, which could be the purpose of a separate function.